# Choppy CSS3 animations in all browsers on Yoga Pro 2

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, performance, lenovo-laptop

This might seem as a broad question because I don't know where to start.
When I compare the same CSS3 animations between my old Lenovo Yoga 13 and my new Lenovo Yoga 2 pro, my old laptop performs much better than the new one.

Everything's fine on my laptop except for CSS3 animations. I have tried on chrome and firefox and it's the same issue.

Both computers don't have a dedicated graphics card.
Specs for the Yoga 13 (i5):
http://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-yoga-13/specs/

Specs for the Yoga 2 Pro (i7):
http://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-yoga-2-pro/specs/

Also not ethat the Yoga 13 is around 2 years older than the Yoga 2 pro.

I understand that you might not be able to help with the question because it's broad, but can you please tell me how I can debug this or where should I seek more information?
Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I ran `dxdiag.exe` on both laptops:
Yoga 13: Intel HD Graphics 4000

[image: Yoga 13 dxdiag]

Yoga 2 Pro: Intel HD Graphics Family (where as in the specs it shows Intel HD Graphics 4400)

[image: Yoga 2 pro dxdiag]

Comment: If you use the same browser versions on both and turn off hardware acceleration in all cases (search the net for browser-specific instructions), does it make any difference at all?

Comment: @karan I disabled hardware acceleration on both (chrome):
on Yoga pro 2: the animation is slightly better but still very choppy
on Yoga 13: animation is still fast - nothing changed
I also noticed that scrolling is smoother on yoga 13 in all cases
Do you think it might be a Drivers issue? I uninstalled it and updated it several times and Windows says I have the latest but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: If you have the latest drivers then I don't know what else to suggest. Is the YP2 heating up a lot?

Comment: @karan not at all.. Any tool I should use to debug?

Comment: To debug the choppiness? Not sure. Say, how much RAM is allocated for graphics in each case? Check the Intel graphics control panel on both, or even the BIOS. Plus how do non-browser animations compare? Animated or live action HD movies (with fast cuts) looking fine on both?

Comment: @karan Just updated the question with dxdiag information from both. Thanks!

Comment: The screen-size on the Yoga 2 is much larger. Dxdiag shows : Display Mode: 3200 x 1800 (32 bit) (60Hz). Do choppy animations happen when the displayed windows are the same size in pixels on both computers?

Comment: @harrymc When I matched the resolution on the Yoga 2 pro with the Yoga 13, animations were showing great! Blazing fast. But problem is, only 1 resolution is recommended by windows which is 3200x1800. I tried all the other variations and some items are not fitting on the screen and a few other things don't look proportionate

Answer (score 7):

The screen-size on the Yoga 2 laptop is much larger.
Dxdiag shows : `Display Mode: 3200 x 1800 (32 bit) (60Hz)`.

As per your tests the Yoga 2 is blazingly fast when using the same 
resolutions, this is probably a hardware limitation on the performance
of the embedded Intel HD Graphics 4400 card.
Embedded video controllers are usually much slower than stand-alone cards.

The best you can do is ensure
that your [Lenovo drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/yoga-series/yoga-2-pro-lenovo?tabName=Downloads) are up-to-date, especially for the Chipset & Display drivers.
Then reboot and see if Windows Update proposes any driver updates in the Optional section.

You can also disable Windows animations to make the user interface
feel faster and more responsive.
See the article [How to disable UI animations in Windows 8.1](http://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-ui-animations-in-windows-8-1/).

If nothing helps, use smaller window sizes for animation and avoid full-screen.
You could also use the Windows Screen resolution applet to reduce it,
in case the 3200-pixels high resolution is not required.
Look also at "Make text and other items smaller", to negate the magnifying effect of
having less screen pixels.

Comment: I updated the chipset drivers (display driver was already up to date).
I don't mind using a smaller resolution but the problem is everything looks wrong when I lower the resolution. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: My idea is to leave the resolution as-is, just to reduce the size of the window in which the animation is playing until its speed is acceptable.

Comment: okay your suggestion is working, but I have to shrink it a lot for it to wait (as if it was a mobile device). Your solution is great, thanks again! I'm just going to give it a few days maybe someone comes up with a different solution

Comment: You could verify in the browser if hardware acceleration is set and to reverse the setting, i.e. set->not-set or the opposite. Sometimes it speeds up the browser.

Comment: Yeah already tried that but it almost had no effect

Comment: I finally fixed! When you told me that the resolution is the issue I was able to solve it. Can you please update your answer?
When I was making my resolution smaller, content was being thrown outside of the viewport, so I opened the Display settings on windows 8.1 (Make text and other items smaller) and chose: Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays and then: Smaller 100%
Now I was able to reduce my resolution to match the Yoga 13 while having all the content inside the viewport! And the animations are as fast!
Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. Did as requested.

Comment: Can you please just add the reference to "Make text and other items smaller" because without this we won't be able to make match the resolution with the Yoga 13

Comment: Did as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Try change vsync to always on. I believe the default setting is application control.

Following is instruction from Intel website:

http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-034107.htm

Online opinion/result of vsync effect on non-gaming graphic performance varies, but doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: What should I do in this case? http://i.imgur.com/WtCMaNQ.png

Comment: In your screen shot, try change the bottom setting "Vertical Sync".

Comment: Yea I mean I just switch it to Driver settings? Because I don't have an On/Off switch

Comment: Click on the "?" and see if it give any instruction to change the settings.

Comment: It's only a help button, I'll try the driver settings now and see if it works, thanks!

Comment: It had no effect, I tried several combinations

Comment: Then this setting has no use in your case, sorry :(